# Replace all occurrences of a word with another specific word that must appear somewhere in the sentence before that word

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, string, regex-group

```py
import re

#example 1
input_text = "((PERSON)María Rosa) ((VERB)pasará) unos dias aqui, hay que ((VERB)mover) sus cosas viejas de aqui, ya que sus cosméticos ((VERB)estorban) si ((VERB)estan) tirados por aquí. ((PERSON)Cyntia) es una buena modelo, su cabello es muy bello, hay que ((VERB)lavar) su cabello"

#example 2
input_text = "Sus útiles escolares ((VERB)estan) aqui, me sorprende que ((PERSON)Juan Carlos) los haya olvidado siendo que suele ((VERB)ser) tan cuidadoso con sus útiles."

#I need replace "sus" or "su" but under certain conditions
subject_capture_pattern = r"\(\(PERSON\)((?:\w\s*)+)\)" #underlined in red in the image
associated_info_capture_pattern = r"(?:sus|su)\s+((?:\w\s*)+)(?:\s+(?:del|de )|\s*(?:\(\(VERB\)|[.,;]))" #underlined in green in the image

identification_pattern = 
replacement_sequence = 

input_text = re.sub(identification_pattern, replacement_sequence, input_text, flags = re.IGNORECASE)
```

this is the correct output:

```py
#for example 1
"((PERSON)María Rosa) ((VERB)pasará) unos dias aqui, hay que ((VERB)mover) cosas viejas ((CONTEXT) de María Rosa) de aqui, ya que cosméticos ((CONTEXT) de María Rosa) ((VERB)estorban) si ((VERB)estan) tirados por aquí. ((PERSON)Cyntia) es una buena modelo,  cabello ((CONTEXT) de Cyntia) ((VERB)es) muy bello, hay que ((VERB)lavar) cabello ((CONTEXT) de Cyntia)"

#for example 2
"útiles escolares ((CONTEXT) NO DATA) ((VERB)estan) aqui, me sorprende que ((PERSON)Juan Carlos) los haya olvidado siendo que suele ((VERB)ser) tan cuidadoso con útiles ((CONTEXT) Juan Carlos)."
```

Details:

Replace the possessive pronouns `"sus"` or `"su"` with `"de " + the content inside the last ((PERSON) "THIS SUBSTRING")`, and if there is no `((PERSON) "THIS SUBSTRING")` before then  replace `sus` or `su` with `((PERSON) NO DATA)`

Sentences are read from left to right, so the replacement will be the substring inside the parentheses `((PERSON)the substring)` before that `"sus"` or `"su"`, as shown in the example.

In the end, the replaced substrings should end up with this structure:

`associated_info_capture_pattern + "((CONTEXT)" + subject_capture_pattern + ")"`

[image]

Comment: What is your question about this task? Is there a problem with your code?

Comment: @mkrieger1 Hello, I need replace the words `"sus"` and `"su"`, so it's inside `((PERSON)` **this string** `)`, and get the output I put in the question. The problem is that I don't know what combination of regex patterns I should do it with. Mmm... I can't get a regex to put in `re.sub()` that allows me to get this output

Comment: Instead of trying to do it all in one `re.sub` (which may require your regex to be very complicated), perhaps try iterating over the matches (like `for m in re.finditer(subject_capture_pattern, input_text): ...`) and inside the loop just apply replacements to the matching slice of the string.

Comment: @TimGoodman It is not necessary that the identification pattern is only one. In fact I was thinking of splitting the string using the `((PERS) )` as a separator. And then in each of the parts I would replace the pronouns `"sus"` and `"su"` for what is inside `((PERS) replace with this name)`. There are several ways to do this, but care must be taken that all `"sus"` or `"su"` must be replaced by the name within the nearest preceding `PERS` (and it is not known exactly how many of them there will be in the `input_string`)

Comment: I added an answer below that I think gets you most of the way there.  (I built the new string out of slices of the original string, but you could do something similar after splitting the string as you suggest.)

Comment: @TimGoodman If I was testing the code of your answer, and it works very well. Then I'll try to use a re.sub() with 2 capturing groups to reorder the context info. Really thanks for the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This shows a way to do the replacement of su/sus like you asked for (albeit not with just a single re.sub). I didn't move the additional info, but you could modify it to handle that as well.

```
import re

subject_capture_pattern = r"\(\(PERSON\)((?:\w\s*)+)\)"

def replace_su_and_sus(input_text):
    start = 0
    replacement = "((PERSON) NO DATA)"
    output_text = ""
    for m in re.finditer(subject_capture_pattern, input_text):
        output_text += re.sub(r"\b[Ss]us?\b", replacement, input_text[start:m.end()])
        start = m.end()
        replacement = m.group(0).replace("(PERSON)", "(CONTEXT) de ")
    output_text += re.sub(r"\b[Ss]us?\b", replacement, input_text[start:])
    return output_text
```

My strategy was:

- Up until the *first* subject capture, replace su/sus with "NO DATA"
- Up until the *second* subject capture, replace su/sus with the name from the *first* capture
- Proceed similarly for each subsequent subject capture
- Finally, replace any su/sus between the last subject capture and the end of the string